# How to use retrofit in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, post, retrofit

I have to use retrofit to consume an api from the server. In my case I have a function that's created on java. I have to recreate it in flutter.
this is the function:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
        public Timestamp saveUser(@RequestBody User user) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            return userService.saveUser(user);
        }
```

My question is how to create the same function in flutter ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this package:
[Retrofit For Dart](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit)

To call Rest API’s by sending headers, parameters, request & response, You can read the documentation. [Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/retrofit/latest/)